# Как динамически скрывать/показывать блок при выборе select с классом или атрибутом disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно? По задумке нужно скрывать блок если выбрана  любая опция с классом **disabled** и показывать во всех остальных случаях.  Как правильно проверить наличие класса или можно через data-set как-то сделать?

CODPEN https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/QWbgXmy

```js
let selectVal = document.querySelector('#select_type');
let divDis = document.querySelector('.divDis');
let divDis2 = document.querySelector('.divDis2');

selectVal.addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(selectVal.classList.contains('disabled')){
    divDis.style.display = "none";
  } else{
    divDis.style.display = "block";
  }  
});
```

```css
.divDis, .divDis2{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<select name="type" id="select_type">
<option value="Yellow" hidden="">Yellow</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Green" class="disabled" >Green</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Purple" class="disabled" >Purple</option>
</select>


<div class="divDis">some text loerm </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс надо проверять не у `select`-а, а у `option`-а.

```js
let selectVal = document.querySelector('#select_type');
let divDis = document.querySelector('.divDis');
let divDis2 = document.querySelector('.divDis2');

selectVal.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var option = selectVal.options[selectVal.selectedIndex];
  if (option.classList.contains('disabled')) {
    divDis.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    divDis.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.divDis,
.divDis2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<select name="type" id="select_type">
  <option value="Yellow" hidden="">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Green" class="disabled">Green</option>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="Purple" class="disabled">Purple</option>
</select>


<div class="divDis">some text loerm </div>
```